# does anyone know of a rails 3 gem for printing t-shirts and mugs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, printing

I am looking for a gem for a service like www.zazzle.com .

Something where I can upload images and get them printed on merchandise like t-shirts and mugs. Then get back a images of the goods with options to buy.

I know zazzle and some of the similar services have api's but I am interested to know if there is a gem out there for any of these services so I don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Is there any other gem is available for custom t-shirt design..I have searched through out of the day but I am not get it any plugin or gem for t-shirt design. Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Best bet for this sort of thing is to head over to http://ruby-toolbox.com/ - you want to look in the [API Clients](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/api_clients.html) category.  There's no zazzle gem, but maybe you will find one of the other services you're interested in there, if not then at least you'll have some examples of gems for web services.